# Problems with ID anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use reload a page to go to an anchor, but the page don't reload or scroll to the anchor. The anchor is not shown till the link is hit.

```js
$('.link').click(function() {
  $('#box').css('display', 'block');
});
```

```css
#box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Description of the content.</p>
</div>
<a href="#box" class="link">Go to #Box</a>
```

This is the page in my blog: `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html#cookies`

For exemple:

1. I open `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html` in a small window (width of 500px, the content is shown).
2. I click in Menu (the content is hidden, the menu is shown).
3. I click in a link `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html#cookies`.
4. The page does nothing (it doesn't reload)!!!

What I want is to go to the page `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html#cookies` on itself.

PS.: It only works when the link is opened in a new window/tab.

It should be opened in a small screen because the problem is happening there (responsive page). Thanks!

Comment: you are using `display:none;`for the element you are aiming to navigate to. The display property 'none' acts as if the element it is applied for is not present in the document, therefore there is o place to navigate / scroll to.

Comment: @BekimBacaj Do you think I can reopen it in the same page? For exemple: I'm in the page `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html` (#cookies is being displayed). I open the menu (#cookies is hidden). I click on the link (then I go to `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html#cookies`).

Comment: sorry but I'm unable to understand both the scenario and the underlying code required to make it happen without a demo. But clean cut is to make that element hidden instead of none using the visibility property. Otherwise leave its display unaltered and give overflow hidden; while setting the height: 0px; and remove it when you want it displayed.

Comment: @BekimBacaj Thanks! I think I'll need to remake everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the anchor is `display:none`, it may as well not exist for the purpose of navigation. Try this styling instead:

```
#box {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Or:

```
#box {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: I can see it working this way. But do you think I can open this link `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html#cookies` in the same page (`http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html#cookies`) to open the page again.

Comment: @PauloDosSantos After setting the location, you could do `location.reload()` to force a page reload. I'm not sure if it will navigate to the correct position though. Browsers usually keep the current scrolling if the location doesn't actually change.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid the current scrolling. Unfortunately, my desing is all connected. If I use   `width:0;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;` or 
  `visibility:hidden;` I would need to rebuild my whole blog from the zero.

Comment: @PauloDosSantos It sounds like you want a single page with a series of sections, all hidden. Clicking a link causes one of these sections to become visible, and only that. Perhaps something like `$('.link').click(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); $('#box').css('display', 'block'); });` would help.

Comment: Okay! I solved my issue in my on application using ` 
        $('#main-wrapper').toggle();
        $('.sidebar-wrapper').toggle();` which I use to show/hide the content and menu. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Its because after refreshing the style is applied to #box so its hidden.

```
#box {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know! I think I need to improve my goal. Do you think I can reopen it in the same page? For exemple: I'm in the page `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html` (#box is being displayed). I open the menu (#box is hidden). I click on the link (then I go to `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html#box`).

Comment: you can achieve this by using query string instead. something like

Comment: It worked the fist time I clicked in the link. But if I open the menu again, the content is hidden again. Thus I can't reopen the link twice. Please, see it `http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/p/politicas.html`

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="box" class="boxContent">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Description of the content.</p>
</div>
<a href="#box" class="link">Go to #Box</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.boxContent {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('.link').click(function() {
  $('#box').toggleClass( "boxContent");
});
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/2TCy4/42/

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate that. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't seem to fit in my concept. I solved that using the jquery I already had running the menu/content system.

Comment: @PauloDosSantos No problem, may be it will use for you in future with different scenario..